# How to give a currently focussed view of the view pager to my custom onClick method?

Tags: android, onclick, android-viewpager

I have an Activity with a ViewPager and I have three layouts. In each layout I have 10 buttons each and i would like to make each button do function on a click. So if i go with the trivial method of defining onClick() method for each button, it is going to be funny and tiresome, because I will have 30 of these setOnClickListener(this) calls and 30 onClick Methods.

On going through the Developers site i found a very important piece of function [android:onClick](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aonClick), using which i can register all the keys to a custom onClick method in the xml file itself, and then on clicking the button, this method of the Activity will be called.

But In my case, using the View pager i have already brought a view into the screen. I have registered a custom onClick Method called **onClickTest()** in my Activity.

```
public void onClickTest(View v) {

        int id = v.getId();
        String idname = getResources().getResourceEntryName(id);    
        Log.i("Sen", "clicked view = "+idname);

        switch (id) {
        case R.id.btn_test:
            testActivity();
            break;
        default:
            break;
}
```

But when i click the button in the viewPager view, i am not able to execute my onClickMethod. I suspect it is not getting the view.

This is the instantiate method of my ViewPager

```
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
            final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) TestActivity.this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    View v0 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout1, null, false);
                    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(v0, 0);
                    return v0;              
                default:
                    return true;
            }
    }
```

The layout1 has 10 keys and **btn_test** is one key in it.

Could you please tell me how to make this working?

Thanks,
Sen

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit disjoint. You talk about multiple `onClick()`, then talk about learning about `android:onClick`, then jump to "registering" an `onClick()` listener though you don't say what `onClickTest()` is tied to.

You could choose any one of those methods and get it working. Try adding `android:onClick="onClickTest"` to your button `btn_test` in the XML. If you already have, show that next time so we're not left guessing what you've already done :).